# Реализации задачи с потоками Pthread Linux

Tags: c, linux

Задание: расчёт суммы соседних элементов массива. Обработка каждой суммы в порождённом потоке. После своего завершения поток выводит идентификатор `pid`. Реализовано с помощью `pthread_create()`. В чём моя ошибка?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int arr[10] = {0,  1, 2, 3, 4 , 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int i;

void* thread_function (void* arg)
{
    int sum = arr[i] + arr[i+1];
    printf("Child pid # %d: %d + %d = %d\n", getpid(), arr[i],arr[i+1], sum);

    //fprintf (stderr, "child thread pid is %d\n", (int) getpid ());
    /* Spin forever. */
    //while (1);
    return NULL;
}

int main ()
{
    pthread_t thread;
    fprintf (stderr, "main thread pid is %d\n", (int) getpid ());

    for(i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    {
        pthread_create (&thread, NULL, &thread_function, NULL);
    }

    /* Spin forever. */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Описано ожидаемое поведение, опишите реальное.

Comment: Автор, не удаляйте вопрос. Он может быть полезен и другим.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Вы неправильно используете переменную `i`.

Она меняется одновременно для всех потоков и функция `thread_function()` "видит" ее текущее состояние, а не то, которое было в момент запуска потока (чего Вы, похоже, ожидаете).

Передавайте ее текущее значение при запуске потока в параметре, например, так (пуристы, без сомнения, обругаются):

```
pthread_create (&thread, NULL, &thread_function, (void *)(long)i);
```

а в начале `thread_function()` напишите:

```
int i = (long)arg;
```

И тренируйтесь дальше!

---

Вообще же, для передачи аргумента в функцию потока можно делать его копию в динамической памяти и передавать этот адрес (освобождать память лучше уже в функции). Без такого способа трудно обойтись, если нужно передать данные, которые не помещаются в `void *` (например, double на 32-bit машине или какую-то структуру).

```
void* thread_function (void* arg)
{
    int i = *(int *)arg;
    free(arg);
    int sum = arr[i] + arr[i+1];
    ...
}

...
for(i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
{
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    *p = i;
    pthread_create (&thread, NULL, &thread_function, p);
}
...
```